# Error adding layer to control on web map using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, ajax

I want to add GeoJSON data to my map, but get an error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setZIndex' of undefined`

```
$.ajax({
  url:'load.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:{state:"",lga:"",raw:""},
  success:function(response){
    if(queryLayer){
      map.removeLayer(queryLayer);
    }

    queryLayer = L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
        var str = "<h5 align=\"center\">" + feature.properties.raw_name + "</h5>";
        str += "<p> State:" + feature.properties.state + " LGA: " + feature.properties.lga + "</p>";

        if(feature.properties.raw_marker !== null &&
          feature.properties.raw_marker  !== undefined &&
          feature.properties.raw_marker  !== ""){
            var customIcon = L.icon({iconUrl: "../"+feature.properties.raw_marker,iconSize:  [28, 38], popupAnchor:  [-3, -15]});
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: customIcon})
                    .bindPopup(str)
                    .on("mouseover",function(){this.openPopup();})
                    .on("mouseout",function(){this.closePopup();})
                    .on('click', function(){searchData(feature);});
        } else {
            return L.marker(latlng)
                    .bindPopup(str)
                    .on("mouseover",function(){this.openPopup();})
                    .on("mouseout",function(){this.closePopup();})
                    .on('click', function(){searchData(feature);});
        }
      }
    }).addTo(map);
      //map.fitBounds(queryLayer.getBounds());
  }
});

overlayMaps = {
  "Industies ": layerIndustries,
  "Raw Materials": queryLayer
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of code missing, so there is a bit of guessing involved, but I would say problem comes from the fact that overlay is being loaded async and not being loaded completely at the time layer control is added to the map.

Solution is to leave `queryLayer` out of `overlayMaps` object and add it to the control after layer is added to the map inside ajax call:

```
myLayerControl.addOverlay(queryLayer, 'Raw Materials');
```

Comment: Thank you,i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to create an empty layer without data: `L.geoJSON()`. Then in the callback add the data to the layer. Something like:

```js
  success:function(response){
    queryLayer.clearLayers();
    queryLayer.addData(JSON.parse(response));
```

At some point you'll need to set the options.

---

I wanted to have the empty layer as a not-selected overlay, not added by default. So only after the user clicks the overlay, then I'll prompt them for settings and do the request.